# Windows iot (c#) - Raspberry PI - I2C

Tags: c#

1.I try to use a Raspberry Pi as a master with a PIC16F1847 as a slave.
The slave send 50 bytes to the master.
However, I have a problem with the C # programming.
Down the C # code is not accepted, the "y" -array.
Can anyone help?
2.This is the code:

```
    private I2cDevice PicDevice;

    public class StartSpanning
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        initI2c();
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadChartContents();
    }

    async void initI2c()
    {
        string i2c1 = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector();                                // Get a selector string that will return all I2C controllers on the system 
        var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(i2c1);
        var I2Csettings = new I2cConnectionSettings(0x05);                          // Adrress PIC
        I2Csettings.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.StandardMode;                            // 100KHz bus speed 
        PicDevice = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(devices[0].Id, I2Csettings);

        byte[] y = new byte[50];
        var result = PicDevice.ReadPartial(y);
    }

    private void LoadChartContents()
    {

        List<StartSpanning> lijst_spanning = new List<StartSpanning>();
        lijst_spanning.Add(new StartSpanning() { Name = "1", Amount = y[0] });
        lijst_spanning.Add(new StartSpanning() { Name = "2", Amount = y[1] });
        lijst_spanning.Add(new StartSpanning() { Name = "3", Amount = y[2] });
        lijst_spanning.Add(new StartSpanning() { Name = "4", Amount = y[3] });
        lijst_spanning.Add(new StartSpanning() { Name = "5", Amount = y[4] });
        lijst_spanning.Add(new StartSpanning() { Name = "6", Amount = y[5] });
        lijst_spanning.Add(new StartSpanning() { Name = "7", Amount = y[6] });
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Down the C # code is not accepted, the "y" -array."?

Comment: y [0], y[1], y[2], ec.. is red underlined.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like y has been declared inside the initI2c method thus it can't be called from the LoadChartContents method.